# Is it possible to point System > Ringtones folder to Memory card > Music?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I want to have custom ringtones and notifictaion tones on my phone. But I don't want to copy every file to the ringtones folder.
Is it possible to make the `System > Ringtones` folder point to `MemCard > Music` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Just isntall some file manager I recommand Total commander, and than when you tap to choose ringtone you will be offered to open it with Total commander or media storage. If this doesn't work than just open to choose ringtone and in upper right corner you will have '+' tap on it and it will open your music player